# How to have continuously scrolling images with no gaps?

Tags: marquee

I am trying to get rid of the space at the start of my scroll.

I have managed - by some miracle as I am not tech savy - to get my images scrolling from left to right continuously across my screen. They are company logos just going round and round. The problem I have is when they come in from the left there is a big white gap until they have stretched across the full screen. How do I get them to to start stretched across the full screen and just keep on going.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It would help a lot if you could make a *minimal* example with the code you used so that other people can analyze your code to see what is causing the problem or to use it to reproduce your problem and give you advice on how to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left">
<img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/603171_0158f68705364e2a98847494c9fdfd06~mv2.png/v1/fill/w_140,h_100/Accord%20Mortgages.png" width="125" height="75" hspace="15" alt="Accord Mortgages">

Comment: Is that what you mean? Even when I remove the direction it still just goes left